# JQuery css relative position with droppable input text box

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I am new to using relative position in CSS.  I am struggling with the html below.  I am running this in IE8.  The issue that I am having is to get my cursor to focus on the text box I have to position it over the top border.

Update: The note above was somewhat resolved by adding z-index to the right div.  What I didn't originally include in my question was that the contents in the left div are assigned to be jQuery draggable and the input text box is a droppable.  I want users to be able to be able to drag in values or enter them on their own.  When z-index is added to the rightDiv, the focus on the text box to allow the user to manually type in an entry works great, but when an entry from the leftDiv is dragged over to the text box it is hidden behind the text box until the drop is complete.

Any suggestions?  Thanks for your help.

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">
<head>
<style>
.rightDiv {
  position : fixed;
  top:90px;
  left:198px;
}
.leftDiv {
  position : relative;
  right : -10px;
  top:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<DIV class=rightDiv>
<INPUT size=10></INPUT>
</DIV>
<DIV class=leftDiv>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
1234<br>
</DIV>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use <!DOCTYPE html> to get IE out of quirks mode, first of all.

Comment: Is not clear what do you want to achieve

Comment: I resolved this.  Thanks for your help.  I simply removed the z-index at the start of the drag and added it back at the end.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not understand ur question well.....but i think you want your textbox top of page

TRY -            .rightDiv
                 {
                  top:90px;
                  left:198px;
                 }

Answer (score 0):

actually the left div containing overlaps the right div so it is not gaining focus 
try with only 2 or 4 "1234
" it would work fine .
This problem is due to relative positioning of the divs try some other way down it would work fine .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what do you want to achieve, but if you want to **get the cursor to focus on the text box** you can put the `.rightDiv` over the `.leftDiv` using `z-index`:

```
.rightDiv {
   position: fixed;
   top: 90px;
   left: 198px;
   z-index: 9999;
}
```

**Check this**: http://jsfiddle.net/XSBqc/1/

**Read all related questions** on sidebar